# contextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("TestRest", "access_token") return authorization code and no JTW token

Tags: authentication, jwt, azure-active-directory, token, openid-connect

I will try to get an authorization token from AzureAd.

I have this configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCookie("TestRestSignInScheme")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("TestRest", options =>
                {
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
                    options.Authority = Configuration["TestRest:Authority"];
                    options.ClientId = Configuration["TestRest:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["TestRest:ClientSecret"];
                    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/test-rest-callback");
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.SignInScheme = "TestRestSignInScheme";  
                });
```

But when i try to get the token with

```
contextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("TestRest", "access_token")
```

the method retunr the authorization code and not the Id_token:

this is the result of the method call:

```
PAQABAAAAAAAm-06blBE1TpVMil8KPQ41ARLOejoQg7gqL67ohJwID-Y1vEGTeU4EEFCui08aki3NbiPOHe-GMHDt3iXTpE0DGovL2RbBA-0kWdD4xxGs4wJ2-s3lPf-yo2M8K5VUXKcsCignlGj7x74vKQrDo_u3zbbJUG5zoc5K2cw4d2rkizHVBLuNZKKqM-654IWDpPWthWLPbGrCPCqQXJnOF0wCfBkFDEb7VSd0nVReNFoGVAYIGE5KgqFQ3WqMpRCqLC4-C-3ZO1I4R7CIDwfBNmB03cOvy4C_-WqaDhVdi5PGDMagQ3WDEdVVzKN-TM4Uwaw4hOidV9xnWrK-NTxcsDTG00NOhotn5i-GDveavdHVAbJrIvJyAwkwxbN88jz5DB-2DDJQW5gRT5ufZl9Th6tZXq2IGpF6eTGIvXDQYBng1D9Sg55Jl_Wt4IT1mRiLH2vlJ-A3cDCaBBJj3-bvu6Bke_GX9MBkdFdH-0lDKhmiHV7pZQD_c3CMtO1KXHktEs5a208mFW-rjSva-DG9laNVx8srdfq-74kjCplUQzbYC13S9-d7L9FB2_3jop95zCADPlwDqz2MuN60DhCJviFn_7USBoQmIcC4pNZalJNckOys3_BLZLNeco6I5gu9PN8gAA
```

is the correct configuration?

Answer (score 0):

1. Here `contextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("TestRest", "access_token")` you're asking for `access_token` not `id_token`. If you need `id_token` - pass `id_token` instead of `access_token`
2. Use official extension from Microsoft [AddAzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)
3. If you need an `access_token` to consume some Azure services like GraphAPI - you can exchange autorization code for an `access_token` using [ADAL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview). Check this sample for details https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-2-TokenCache

`id_token` is used by your application to sign in user.

`access_token` allows your application to consume another service.